# C# NAudio How to force/hardcode audio device (soundcard)?

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to force an audio device into an NAudio player but I've been unable to work it out. At the moment, the code I have inherited uses a comboBox to select the device and use it, but I want to hard code it in.

From the code below in the commented lines you can see what I have already tried, but they all show errors so I am not getting it right somehow.

Can anyone help me with this?

The outcome I desire is to 'force' the NAudio to use the "Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)" audio device instead of selecting it from the combo box.

Thank you

```
NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.Active);
Globals.NewDevice = devices.ToString();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());



if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
    var device = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    //var device = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice.Equals.("Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)"); 
    //var device = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice)."Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)";
    //var device = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice)"Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)";
    //var device = NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice."Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)";
    //var device = (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice.ReferenceEquals."Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can just do this:

```
comboBox1.Text = "Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)";
```

Thanks for the downvotes...